# Proper way to delete a record from database in Titanium Alloy

Tags: mobile, titanium, titanium-alloy

I'm working on my first Titanium App...

The way you save a record is:

```
var apple = Alloy.createModel('apples', { 
    color: 'red',
    created: Date.now()
});
apple.save();
```

Simple, so how do you delete a record (given its alloy_id) from the db, in a similar simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model in Alloy is Backbone model in fact. You can use [`destroy()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-destroy) method.